# JavaScript add EventListener

Tags: javascript

I have make the html by javascript. how we can find out the which delete button is pressed

```
<div id="maindiv">        
    <div id="product_1">
        <input placeholder="Add Product Name" type="text">
        <input placeholder="Cost per unit" type="number">
        <input placeholder="Number of products" type="number">
        <button id="delete_1">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div id="product_2">
        <input placeholder="Add Product Name" type="text">
        <input placeholder="Cost per unit" type="number">
        <input placeholder="Number of products" type="number">
        <button id="delete_2">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: find out the who ???

Comment: Where is the EventListner?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right

Comment: add event listener on your delete button and find the product ID and perform delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `this`

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')
btn.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked id: ' + this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="product_1">
    <input placeholder="Add Product Name" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Cost per unit" type="number">
    <input placeholder="Number of products" type="number">
    <button id="delete_1">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div id="product_2">
    <input placeholder="Add Product Name" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Cost per unit" type="number">
    <input placeholder="Number of products" type="number">
    <button id="delete_2">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. Hope this helps.

```js
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log(this.id);

})
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id='delete'>Delete</button>
<button id='save'>Save</button>
</body>
```